# Defining a function in Scheme Programming from a List?

Tags: scheme

Define a function (possible Schedule) which takes a single parameter, Schedule, and returns #T or #F. Schedule is a list of (stage start_time stop_time) triples, where each stage is a positive integer and each start_time and stop_time is an integer in the range 0-2399, representing the start and stop times of a show, using 24-hour time. The function should return #T if the schedule is possible to carry out -- i.e., if the schedule contains no conflicts -- and #F otherwise.

You may assume that list Schedule will be in the correct format when the function is called; you do not have to error-check for a non-list or an incorrectly formed list. The events in list Schedule are not necessarily sorted by stage numbers, starting times, or any other order. In your program, you may write and call any additional functions that are helpful in the computation.

Examples:

```
(possible '(
    (1 1030 1100)
    (2 900 1000)
    (3 1400 1430)
))
```

should return #T,

```
(possible '(
    (1 900 930)
    (2 900 1000)
    (3 1400 1430)
))
```

should return #F,

```
(possible '(
    (7 1130 1200)
    (12 900 1000)
    (2 1500 1530)
    (2 1430 1500)
))
```

should return #T, and

```
(possible '(
    (7 1130 1200)
    (12 900 1000)
    (2 1500 1530)
    (5 1430 1500)
))
```

should return #F.

I tried to create a fix list like :

> define (Schedule car )
>   (Schedule '((( 1 1030 1100) (2 900 1000) (3 1400 1430)))
>   return #T for first three schedules

Comment: Why should the last one be `#f`?

Comment: (2 1500 1530)
(5 1430 1500)
They have conflict since the stop_time of stage 5 ( 1500) have conflict with start_time (1500) of stage 2 .

Comment: Then the third should also be #f?

Comment: Not necessary .The events in list Schedule are not necessarily sorted by stage numbers, starting times, or any other order. 
I have well written this program in java by OOP  but with Scheme I got stuck . In Scheme , I think I just create a fixed list of Schedule above but I don't know how to return True/False by use car or cdr ?

Comment: The third should return TRUE since they have the same stage 2 . You don't need to go from one stage to the other .

Comment: OK, think I got it. See my update.

Answer (score 3):

Nice question; pity you didn't show us the efforts you made (if any). Here's an example in [Racket](http://racket-lang.org):

```
(define (possible schedule)
  ; sort by start time
  (let ((s (sort schedule < #:key cadr)))
    (andmap (lambda (f s) 
              ; either end time of first < start time of second
              (or (< (caddr f) (cadr s)) 
                  ; or they are equal AND it's the same stage
                  (and (= (caddr f) (cadr s)) (= (car f) (car s)))))
            (drop-right s 1)
            (cdr s))))
```

Comment: Is the Scheme syntax same with Racket ?

Comment: Probably not, but close. You didn't say which Scheme (which implementation, which standard RnRS) so I can't really tell you.

Comment: I use Scheme from s48.org
Scheme 48 is an implementation of Scheme written by Richard Kelsey and Jonathan Rees

Comment: I don't have that implementation. If have linked to the Racket docs, if necessary. Please try it yourself and report back if you have any problems.

Comment: I did tried your codes:
error: unknown # syntax [read]
  #\:
  #{&read-error}
       #{&i/o-port-error #{input-port #{input-channel "standard inp
>   (andmap (lambda (f s)
     ; either end time of first < start time of second
       (or (< (caddr f) (cadr s))
                ; or they are equal AND it's the same stage
                (and (= (cadr s) (caddr f)) (= (car f) (car s)))))
          (drop-right s 1)
          (cdr s)))
assertion-violation: undefined variable [global]
                     s
                     user

warning: discarding extraneous right parenthesis [read-command]

Comment: How can I check:
(possible '(
    (1 1030 1100)
    (2 900 1000)
    (3 1400 1430)
))
return #T,

Comment: Seems it doesn't like the internal `define`; changed by a `let`.

Comment: Is s undefined variable ?
error: unknown # syntax [read]
       #\:
       #{&read-error}
       #{&i/o-port-error #{input-port #{input-channel "standard input" 0}}}

Comment: Scheme48 is a R5RS with some implementation specific extras. It doesn't have `andmap` (but could get `every` from [SRFI-1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html)), `#:key` in sort (which you can work around by putting the accessor in the sort procedure) and `drop-right` (exists in SRFI-1)

Comment: @Sylwester Thanks, I guess that with that information the OP should be able to find his way.